# How to get the longest item in intellisense presenter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm creating my own intellisense presenter of VS, I want to bind the presenter's width to the width of the longest item, but I don't know how to get the longest item, anyone can help?

Comment: If you show your work to people, they can help better `;)`

Comment: As an aside to your efforts to create what is most likely a plugin or extension; if you do; make sure it doesn't a) hog memory or b) cause random Visual Studio crashes. I've given up on almost all visual studio extensions because of a and b being an all too common occurence. The only extension I have installed is nuget. I recognise that this is not answering your question... ;-)

Comment: Use a foreach loop, to go trough all your items and save the highest .Length value. when a new item has a higher length, put down the new number.